# Where can i find the create order logic code for "Submit order" button in magento 1 backend?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I can see that `"order.submit()"` is called from create order button but i am not sure where is the logic is located.

Issue is order does not created on first click on create order button due to that ia m trying to debug the issue.

Any thoughts where i can find the responsible file in magento 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Frontend:**
If you see `checkout/onepage/reviews/info.phtml` file you may find a code like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
//]]>
</script>
```

You can see the URL route `checkout/onepage/saveOrder` which is triggered on order submit. The action path for this route will be `saveOrderAction()` in file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`.

**For Admin Side:**

The sales order create view comes `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create.php`. Where you could find the line

```
$this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', "order.submit()");
```

You can see the `order.submit()` is called when you click save button. The order object is created in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form.phtml` see code below

```
var order = new AdminOrder(<?php echo $this->getOrderDataJson() ?>);
```

The `AdminOrder` class comes from `js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js`, you may find the `submit()` in this file which calls `editform.submit()`.

The Edit form is available in same `form.phtml` with action url of controller save action.

```
<form id="edit_form" action="<?php echo $this->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The definition of `$this->getSaveUrl()` is available at `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Form.php`

```
public function getSaveUrl()
{
   return $this->getUrl('*/*/save');
}
```

The Controller action is `saveAction()` from `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php`

Hope it was helpful for you to get the flow.
Thanks

Comment: For backend ???

Comment: Actually i am checking for magento backend.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I still do not get idea about from where the save action is called ? when submit button is clicked from backend

Comment: Please see the updated answer. And please do upvote if it helped you. :)

Comment: <button id="id_3bf2296eea716ef862e16e6d1ebd4395" title="Submit Order" type="button" class="scalable save" onclick="order.submit()" style=""><span><span><span>Submit Order</span></span></span></button>

Comment: I am not where is the  "submit" function for  onclick="order.submit()"